# Make a page loaded in an IFRAME access the JavaScript objects of the containing page's script

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page called Parent.html, which has some inline JavaScript code, and it also has an IFRAME in which it loads another page named Child.html.

I want that the JavaScript code inside Child.html be able to reference the JavaScript objects declared inside Parent.html.

Is that possible? I tried it and it didn't work. Please see the code below.

**Parent.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "jQuery.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            var Foo = 
            {
                Initialize: function()
                {
                    alert('Hello, I am Foo.');
                },

                SomeVariable : 'I am a property of the Foo class.'
            };

            $(document).ready( function() { Foo.Initialize(); } );
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Parent</h1>

        <p>This is the parent Web page.</p>

        <p>
            <IFRAME src = "child.html" height = "400" width = "800"></IFRAME>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Child.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function() { Foo.Initialize(); alert(Foo.SomeVariable); } );
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h4>Child</h4>

        <p>This is the child Web page.</p>

        <p>
            I am a child.

            <script>

            </script>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way for such pages to share data between them?

Comment: you of course cannot use jQuery in the frame if it is not available in the frame. You can however use the parent's jQuery

Comment: Thank you. Do you want to make it an answer and I'll check it as the right one? :-)

Comment: Who? Me? I think Phil's answer demonstrates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.top.Foo.Initialize()` or `window.parent.Foo.Initialize()`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.parent

Note that access across windows is subject to the [*same origin policy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks very much. 9 minutes to go before I mark your answer as the right one.